# Vertical datum transformation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, dem, geoid, vertical-transformation

I'd like to compare USGS 3DEP DEM with SRTM DEM for western U.S.. I did some research [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/geoid.htm), and find out that I need to match their datum (from NAD83-NAVD 88 to WGS84-EGM 96) before comparing the value.
By following [FAQ: How do I apply a vertical datum transformation in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000015147), I convert my SRTM DEM into point layer by using [3D feature by attribute](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/feature-to-3d-by-attribute.htm), define its projection to be EGM 96, and project it to NAVD 88.

I first try a conversion from EGM96to WGS84 Ellipsoid (so I only change vertical datum), and it succeed with result matching [this site](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/vdatumweb/). However, I couldn't follow the ESRI artical's method when trying to convert both horizontal and vertical projection. So I tried following steps:

1. I follow ESRI suggested steps, that convert horizontal WGS84-NAD83 first, and do vertical projection next. However, since my intermediate result lacks vertical datum, ArcGIS Pro does not allow me to perform vertical projection. (that 'vertical' option in Project is not available) Meanwhile, the result seems wrong since the projected point layer overlap input point layer.
2. I tried to change both horizontal and vertical projection simultaneously. This time the horizontal projection seems working (all points shifts a bit). But when I use 'calculate geometry' to calculate z-value, the new z-value is same as before. (The VDatum website shows a 0.65m difference at my test point.)

Any suggestions about my error or work-around methods?

Comment: Convert the original datasets to geotiffs or IMG files and use vDatum to do the transformations :  https://vdatum.noaa.gov/

Comment: Do you have the coordinate system data setup installed?

Comment: @GBG: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried both online and offline versions of VDatum, using .tiff, .shp, ASCII (ESRI .txt) and ASCII (VDatum format, Long/Lat/Height columns) formats, but none is working. The .tiff and .shp always shows processing with 0% progress. When using ASCII format VDatum keeps telling me to choose West Coast region while I'm using that already.

Comment: @mkennedy Are you talking about [this](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/arcgis-pro-coordinate-systems-data/td-p/462850)? I haven't tried that yet, but will look into it.